# Laravel 5 How to add multiple foreign key constraints to a User on creation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I now know that I can create a User using the haveMany relationship between a Region and User by doing this:

```
$region = Region::find($data['region_id']);

$region->users()->create([
   'username' => $data['username'],
   'email' => $data['email'],
   'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
   'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
   'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);
```

But what if there are multiple foreign keys, how do you create a user without making them fillable for more than 1 foreign key constraint?  What if there were 3 or 4?

Example of the relationships setup in the different models:

```
Region hasMany Users, or
User belongsTo a Region

Location hasMany Users, or 
User belongsTo a Location
```

A stripped down version of my migration looks like this if it helps to understand the relationships better:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('region_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('region_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('regions');

        $table->foreign('location_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('locations');
    });

    Schema::create('regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('street_address', 100);
        $table->string('city', 50);
        $table->string('province', 50);
        $table->string('country', 50);
        $table->string('postal_code', 10);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Example of Region and Location Models:

```
/**
 * Region may have many users.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}


/**
 * Location may have many users.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Location');
}
```

Comment: Don't you just add `$this->hasMany()` to the user model as many as you need to define them?

Comment: Hi @Blkc, I've got a hasMany from Regions to User, and the reverse belongsTo from User to Regions.  I also have a hasMany from Locations to Users, and the reverse belongsTo from Users to Locations.  So the relationship is there, and if I do: Region::find(1)->create([ ...])  I get a User with a Region, but no location_id is set unless I pass it into create and make location_id fillable.  From what I've been told that is not how you do it.  So was thinking there must be a way to do this in the ORM: Region::find(1)->create([ ...])->location('23');

Comment: The thing is from what you are describing I am still seeing the common thing between Region and Location is User so why don't you pass a User::create in the User model and fill both the reference id to Location and Region?  If I am mistaken then can you show me what your 3 tables (Region, User, Location) looks like?

Comment: Hi @Blkc, I was told it isn't good practice to make foreign keys like region_id and location_id fillable and pass in values and instead I should use the ORM like the first snippet where I create a User using the region relationship, but then I have to pass in the location_id to be filled.  Wanted to know if I could do something else like: $region->users()->create([...])->withLocation(32); (I just made that up as an example).  Maybe I should be making foreign keys fillable after all?

Comment: But the thing is let's say your region_id is 2 in your User table, your Region table should also has its primary id as 2 respectively. That is kinda why we need foreign key and local key. I don't see the reason as to why invoking another model in a model would be a bad thing.

Comment: Not sure about what you need the regions and locations for in your application, but another thing you can do is to set your location and regions standard and do a dropdown for your users in the UI. That way your primary keys in your Region table and Location table would not change and you can just mess around in the User table/Model.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a model for Region and Location.  Each of your region has an id and location has an id, then just add

```
$this->hasMany('where your Region model is', 'region_id', 'id');
$this->hasMany('where your Location model is', 'location_id', 'id');
```

to your User model

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#one-to-many

Edit: You can also do in any of your model

```
if ($this->create()) {
  return (new Model())->create(the params you need in another model);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I already have this in my code, but when you run $region->users()->create([...]) from the first code snippet, the location_id will never be set unless I make location_id fillable in the Users model, and foreign keys shouldn't be made fillable.  So I can create a User with either a region by using the first code snippet in the question, or I can create a user in a similar fashion with a location_id, but I don't understand how to create a User that will have both the region_id and location_id set.

Comment: so User table contains region_id, location_id, and user_id as the primary; Region table contains region_id as the primary, user_id; then you can just link region_id to region_id and user_id to user_id, same goes for location? As my last comment on your question you might need to show your tables in your question.

Comment: Hi, I added my schemas to the question.  Sorry I'm very new to Laravel and I seem to know enough to do easier right out of the docs examples, but I'm just completely confused on how to use the ORM outside of simple relationships.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're saying now... do you mean I can invoke $region->users()->create([...]); and inside Users create take out whatever I need out of the collection to create a Location?  When it returns the id of the Location created, do you just mass assign the new location_id by making it fillable in Users?

Comment: Yes kinda like that. I think as long as you can keep the foreign key and the local key the same value in both tables you can do whichever method you want.