# How to define Multiple foreignKeys in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In my Model class;
Currently I have defined like;

> return $this->belongsTo(***related***: Site::class,
>   ***foreignKey:***'SiteId', ***ownerKey***:'SiteId');; ----->This works.

But I want to define a combination as Foreign key, 
eg: CompanyCode+SiteId

My Current and Target model has both columns(ie:CompanyCode+SiteId). That combination will return a single entry.I want to retrieve that in my current model.

How can I do that?

My **Site** Model is like;

```
class Site extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'vwSitesPortal';
    protected $primaryKey = 'SiteId';
```

...

My Current model is like;

```
class Alarm extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'vwAlarm';
    protected $primaryKey = 'AlarmId';
...
  public function Site()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(**related**: Site::class,
**foreignKey**:'SiteId', **ownerKey:**'SiteId'
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to create a new column to save combined foreignKey.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra I have updated my question. Sorry, I couldn't get your point. Where should I store it?

Comment: Look at this issue, I think laravel doesn't support composite foreign keys  https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355

Comment: This may help you, please visit this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/how-i-can-put-composite-keys-in-models-in-laravel-5

Comment: @SagarGautam, So how can I achieve my requirement? Is there any alternative way available?

Comment: I've just added link of similar question. look at answer with 34 votes, I think that may help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {

$table->integer('lecture_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->timestamps();

$table->primary(['lecture_id', 'user_id']);

$table->foreign('lecture_id')
      ->references('id')->on('lectures')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

});

```
see this example
```

Comment: Im not using any schema. My models are talking to existing Tables/Views.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419953/laravel-5-how-to-add-multiple-foreign-key-constraints-to-a-user-on-creation

See this example